# TypeError [.ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

In running code suddenly getting this error. I tried everything like deleted the n`od_module` folder and `"react-scripts": "^3.4.0"`.

My node version is `12.16.2`. My react version `16.13.1`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you post need more information.